# What options are available to manage the error "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable/immutable"?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

This question is not about why the compiler gives these errors — I think I understand that. This question is about how to manage the situation on the mutable path while hoping to be able to call other functions.

This is a simplification of what I am trying to do. I have a lot of `Foo`s inside `World` and I need to update them based on other data from `World`. I have several private functions inside `World` that I would like to be able to call.

```
pub struct Foo {
    id: i32,
    //...
}

pub struct Bar {
    //...
}

pub struct World {
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
    bars: Vec<Bar>,
    //...
}

impl World {

    pub fn create() -> World {
        World {
            foos: Vec::new(),
            bars: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn update(&mut self) {
        for foo in self.get_foos_mut() {
            //error[E0XXX]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable/imutable ...
            let _bar = self.get_bar_given_foo(foo);
            //alter foo based on bar and other world things calling other world functions...
            //...
        }
    }

    //some useful utility functions that should be called several times
    //from different World places...

    fn get_foos_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [Foo] {
        //select slice interval based on foos or any other calculation using self data...
        &mut self.foos[..]
    }

    fn get_bar_given_foo(&self, foo: &Foo) -> &Bar {
        //select bar based on foo or any other calculation using self data...
        &self.bars[foo.id as usize]
    }

    //other utility functions that abstract e sequence of operations that I would 
    //like to use on the update path...    
}

fn main() {
    let mut world = World::create();
    world.update();
}
```

You can also [run the code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=142a3f98477f6bb18b86a1a1445c83d2).

It looks a very limiting situation because when on a mutable path like the `update` function, I am unable to call any of the private methods from `self`.

Since I don't want to clone all the data, I could think of three solutions. I tried 1 and 2 and both work.

1. **Inline everything**. Since this solution works for the example above, it looks like the compilation error is caused by the limitation of the Rust compiler that as I understand: it just looks the function signature and not the implementation of the functions.
2. **Create functions that receive references to what they need**. There is no need borrow `self` again. The function `World::get_foos_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [Foo]` could be removed and created a new one outside `World`: `fn world_get_foos_mut(foos: &mut Vec<Foo>) -> &mut [Foo]` The code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=142a3f98477f6bb18b86a1a1445c83d2) shows this solution.
3. **Create macros instead of regular functions?** Since they are macros I suspect that there won't be any borrow involved. Since I am not familiar with macros I am unable to tell if this works or how to do this yet.

I really need other options because Solution 1 is not viable in my opinion and solution 2 looks very cumbersome and fragile (it looks that I might have the same problems but with the references inside `World`).

I am really frustrated about not being able to find the correct model to handle this.

Will the Rust compiler try to analyze these situations in the future?

Comment: My recommended solution from the duplicates: [create more structs](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2153a80f000de253a91452c2eb2abb56). Effectively the concept of moving the functions out of `World` but putting them into new structs instead of being bare.

Comment: For what it's worth, all 3 of your solutions are the same: The compiler can know that fields of a struct are disjoint and wont overlap, but only inside of a single function. This is deliberate and not a thing to be "fixed" in the future (as discussed in the duplicates). Inlining code (using a macro or not) moves it into a single function, so the compiler can validate the code. Creating fine-grained functions does the same in the other direction: if you only pass in a part of your struct, there's no way that other fields could be modified.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster, I appreciate your time for pointing out the duplicates and suggesting me the solution in create_more_structs. I will need some time to go through all of this.

Comment: You are quite welcome. I commend you for correctly identifying the core "workaround". I'm a Rust fanboy, but I honestly think that the smaller structs that I create in these cases helps my code have a better structure.